# Javascript Matrix Calculator with HTML form

Tags: javascript, foreach, forms, matrix-multiplication

I have a website that teaches students finite math http://finitehelp.com.
On the site I have a calculator that does combinations and permutations and now I am trying to include a matrix calculator that will add, subtract, multiply, and inverse matrices.

I am using Javascript and the sylvester library http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/ to do the calculations. I was able to successfully create a program that would take values entered into a form by a user and do the calculations but this only works for a matrix of a specific size (4x4).

What I cannot figure it out is how to only take values from a form which are not null and create a matrix out of them and then output those values into the appropriate fields in the result form.

Some Sylvester methods I am using

```
// create matrix from embedded array and assign to var A
var A = $M([
  [8,3,9],
  [2,0,7],
  [1,9,3]
]);

// create matrix from embedded array and assign to var B
var B = $M([
  [4,1,2],
  [1,5,3],
  [1,7,2]
]);

 // Multiply AB
 A.x(B)

 // assign product of A.x(B) to var res
 var res = A.x(B)

 // return the 1,1 element of res
 res.e(1,1)
```

In my form the biggest matrix you can put in is 6x6 because they will never need to calculate matrices larger than this.

What I need the program to do is detect how large the matrices are, create sylvester matrices out of them, and assign them to variables. Once they are variables I can use sylvester to do the operations but I also will need to know how to output the results into a form.

Here is what I have so far

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('mbutton').onclick = doCalc;
    document.getElementById('subtbutton').onclick = doCalc;
    document.getElementById('addbutton').onclick = doCalc;
}
function doCalc() {
    // assign the inputted values to variables
    var Aval1 = document.matrixCalc.AR1C1.value,
        Aval2 = document.matrixCalc.AR1C2.value,
        Aval3 = document.matrixCalc.AR2C1.value,
        Aval4 = document.matrixCalc.AR2C2.value,
        Bval1 = document.matrixCalc.BR1C1.value,
        Bval2 = document.matrixCalc.BR1C2.value,
        Bval3 = document.matrixCalc.BR2C1.value,
        Bval4 = document.matrixCalc.BR2C2.value;  

    // make matrices out of the inputted values and assign to variables
    var A = $M([
        [Aval1,Aval2],
        [Aval3,Aval4]
        ]);
    var B = $M([
        [Bval1,Bval2],
        [Bval3,Bval4]
        ]);  
    // if user clicks multiply button make the values of
    // the answer form show the appropriate values
    if (this.value == "x") {
        var res = A.x(B);
        document.matrixCalc.PR1C1.value = res.e(1,1);
        document.matrixCalc.PR1C2.value = res.e(1,2);
        document.matrixCalc.PR2C1.value = res.e(2,1);
        document.matrixCalc.PR2C2.value = res.e(2,2);
    } else if (this.value == "-") {
        var res = A.subtract(B);
        document.matrixCalc.PR1C1.value = res.e(1,1);
        document.matrixCalc.PR1C2.value = res.e(1,2);
        document.matrixCalc.PR2C1.value = res.e(2,1);
        document.matrixCalc.PR2C2.value = res.e(2,2);
    } else if (this.value == "+") {
        document.matrixCalc.PR1C1.value = parseFloat(Aval1) + parseFloat(Bval1);
        document.matrixCalc.PR1C2.value = parseFloat(Aval2) + parseFloat(Bval2);
        document.matrixCalc.PR2C1.value = parseFloat(Aval3) + parseFloat(Bval3);
        document.matrixCalc.PR2C2.value = parseFloat(Aval4) + parseFloat(Bval4);
    }
}
```

HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="sylvester.src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="matrices.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="matrixCalc" action="">
<div id="matrix-a">
    <p>Matrix A</p>
    <input type="text" name="AR1C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR1C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR1C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR1C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR1C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR1C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                 
    <input type="text" name="AR2C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR2C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR2C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR2C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR2C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR2C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                 
    <input type="text" name="AR3C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR3C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR3C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR3C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR3C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR3C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                 
    <input type="text" name="AR4C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR4C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR4C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR4C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR4C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR4C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                 
    <input type="text" name="AR5C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR5C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR5C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR5C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR5C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR5C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                 
    <input type="text" name="AR6C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR6C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR6C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR6C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR6C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="AR6C6" size="4" />
</div>
<div id="matrix-b">
    <p>Matrix B</p>                       
    <input type="text" name="BR1C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR1C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR1C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR1C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR1C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR1C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                             
    <input type="text" name="BR2C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR2C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR2C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR2C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR2C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR2C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                             
    <input type="text" name="BR3C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR3C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR3C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR3C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR3C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR3C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                
    <input type="text" name="BR4C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR4C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR4C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR4C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR4C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR4C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                
    <input type="text" name="BR5C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR5C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR5C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR5C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR5C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR5C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                
    <input type="text" name="BR6C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR6C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR6C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR6C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR6C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="BR6C6" size="4" />
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="button" id="mbutton" value="x" />
    <input type="button" id="addbutton" value="+" />
    <input type="button" id="subtbutton" value="-" />
</div>
<div id="matrix-c">
    <p>Answer</p>
    <input type="text" name="PR1C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR1C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR1C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR1C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR1C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR1C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                
    <input type="text" name="PR2C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR2C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR2C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR2C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR2C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR2C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                
    <input type="text" name="PR3C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR3C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR3C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR3C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR3C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR3C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                               
    <input type="text" name="PR4C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR4C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR4C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR4C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR4C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR4C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                
    <input type="text" name="PR5C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR5C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR5C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR5C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR5C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR5C6" size="4" />
    <br/>                                 
    <input type="text" name="PR6C1" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR6C2" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR6C3" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR6C4" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR6C5" size="4" />
    <input type="text" name="PR6C6" size="4" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. When answering please keep in mind that this is only the second time I've tried to write a program so that little bit extra in the explanation could help a great deal. Thank you.

Comment: what would you want to do if the user randomly leaves boxes blank? throw some kind of error?

Comment: Are these always square matrices?

Comment: If they left a box blank then filled in another after in the same row then yes that would have to be an error or it would be assumed the empty value was a zero. Such as 3 2 blank 5 would be an error but 3 2 7 5 would assume that the matrix is 4 columns.

Comment: No they are not always square.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find it better to use a textarea and let users type in matrices in a much more natural format. It will require parsing the content, but that's not hard. That way users can create any size matrix. I can post a generic "parse textarea content to make an array" function a little later.

Also, the maths isn't that hard. I did it some time ago (products, addition, determinants) but can't find where I put it. Determinants were the most difficult, if I remember correctly it was a simple matter of splitting larger matrices into 2x2 matrices and adding and subtracting their determinants (everything I needed was on the Wolfram web site).

Comment: +1 for the `textarea` it'll take way less time to enter the data.

Comment: Yes that would be more user friendly, I will look into it.